# Binary equation with encryption

Tags: encryption, xor

I'm trying to test the ring signature scheme proposed by Rivest Shamir and Tauman in the famous paper "How to leak a secret".

One of the step consist in

> 4) the signer solves the following ring equation for y1: Ck,v(y1,y2,y3)=v"

I have everything except $y_1$.

It's defined that

> $C_k,v(y_1,y_2,y_3) = E_k(y_1 \oplus E_k(y_2 \oplus E_k(y_3 XOR v)))$

where $E_k$ means symmetric encryption with the key $k$.

So what I have to solve is something like:

$y_1 = ? \\  
y_2 = 1010 \\   
y_3 = 1011 \\   
v = 0011$

I have no idea whatsoever on how to solve this. Can you at least tell me if this is possible?

I know that I should provide k and other things but the only thing i need to know if it is possible to actually solve that thing above and how.
In reality I'm using 64 bits binary numbers, not 4 bits.

The main question is: can I solve this for $x$, knowing the key $k$?

$$E_k( BinaryNumber \oplus x ) = BinaryNumber$$

Comment: Decrypt and then XOR.

Comment: Are you telling me that Ek(Binary number) XOR Ek (unknown) is the same as Ek(Binary number XOR unknown) ?

Comment: And of course this is not working... for example using E(f999 XOR a123) = ad8b4583635c2f1b), whereas doing E(f999)XOR E(a123) gives e87a515b1c28eba2. Both time with the same key 63 using DES in ECB. every number is hexadecimal, including the key.

Comment: I'm telling you that x=Dk(BinaryNumber)XOR BinaryNumber.